Ordering pie in ggplot by frequency
I have a data frame that looks at the frequency of species of bacteria.
Despite the species being ordered by descending frequency in my data frame, ggplot output places the order of both the pie chart and the legend in alphabetical order, I am looking to reorder it to descending frequency, but am having difficulty doing this.
Here is my data frame:
data
Below is the code used:
ggplot(NTM_Data, aes(x="", y=Frequency, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() +
   theme(legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.3)), legend.title = element_text(size=rel(1.8))) +
    labs( fill = "Species - Frequency (%)")+
  ggtitle("The Frequency and Percentage of all Nontuberculous Mycobacteria") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=-0.25)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 25)) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_text(size=21)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=16)) 



The order of your dataset is not (that) important. If you want a specific order you have to convert your variable to a factor and set your desired order, e.g. try with NTM_Data$Species <- reorder(NTM_Data$Species, NTM_Data$Frequency). For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Thanks, this worked, but put the species in the legend in ascending frequency order, any way to flip it to descending?

Try + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) to reverse the order of the legend.
